# Strategies for UK migration as a software dev?

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas, resident-permit

**Goal:** What would be the easiest way to migrate to the UK and live there permanently?

**Possible Options I can think of:**

- **Option 1:** Apply for a job that offers Visa Sponsorship. Then get sponsored to move over under the 5 year visa. I'm not really fully in
  the range of Senior developer, so more likely to have luck with
  Intermediate developer jobs, which I don't think are covered in the
  skills shortage list.
- **Option 2:** Apply for the 2 year youth mobility visa, and then apply for all jobs over there remotely, even if it's not visa sponsored. I'm unsure what
  would happen at the end of the 2 years?
- **Option 3:** Apply for the 2 year youth mobility visa, move to the UK with nothing and then apply for  contract jobs and the like.
- **Option 4:** Go and study something in the UK, and then try and find another development job after a year of studying.

**My Status:**
I have been trying to apply for the jobs offering Visa sponsorship, but without achieving any interviews yet. People I have talked to usually recommend Option 3, but this worries me a lot because applying for jobs is really tough/stressful for me (I might be a low-mid grade candidate) and applying for jobs from a position of unemployment makes you an undesirable candidate and more desperate.

**Background:**

Home country: New Zealand

Desired Destination: London, UK

Field: Software Development

Experience: 4.5 years

Age: <25

Education level: Bachelors

Comment: My broader intention is to move to a large richer city/country in the EU, but limited the question to the UK to hopefully avoid generic advice and a question that was too broad. Other places I'm also looking at so far: Amsterdam, Switzerland, Germany, etc.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a grandparent who was born in the UK? If so, you could be eligible for the [UK Ancestry visa](https://www.gov.uk/ancestry-visa).

Comment: Nope, afraid not.